# What is event in context of Netflix technology?

Tags: netflix

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WuRazsX-MBY) link, @4.49sec speaker talks about some stats. He mentions 'event'.

What exactly event here means in programming terms?

Comment: The speaker starts listing examples of events 20 seconds later!

Answer (score 1):

An event in this case basically means a message with some data in it. Later in the video he mentions examples like session data, tracing data etc. 
You can put e.g. a user id in it, and an action that the user did, when the event was created. Consumers can then create statistics and react on those events (you could for example create a new movie recommendation, when the user finished watching a movie, and you have ingested that event).